# How can I change hierarchy order in a D3 nest?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a dataset that could be grouped in under either of two categorizations.  I'd like to initially nest the data in one categorization, but then have the option of switching the categorization nesting dynamically.

Here is the initial set-up of my data:

```
var dataset = [list of objects];
var nestedData = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.category1; })
    .key(function(d) { return d.category2; })
    .entries(dataset);
```

I'd like to resort the hierarchy such that it would be equivalent to if I had initially done:

```
var nestedData = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.category2; })
    .key(function(d) { return d.category1; })
    .entries(dataset);
```

The best way I've figured out how to do it is by going back to the original dataset, but that feels really hacky.

Comment: Resetting original dataset sounds totally legit to me, what's hacky in that?

Comment: It forces me to keep the original dataset, and it forces me to update the original dataset every time I change nestedData.

Comment: Yes, but what's bad in that? You'll have original model and view model. Avoiding that is premature optimization. In fact, it's not time of 8086 processors with 4kb RAM.